# Xamarin Bind to a property (List of Custom type object) in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a custom type `HomeItem` and a Content page `HomePage` which has a property `HomeItemsSource` (this is an `ObservableCollection` of `HomeItem`). `HomeItemsSource` is used a an Itemsource in a ListView.

The Listview contains a custom view `CardsHolder` in `HomePage` , I want to bind to a property `Items` of the `HomeItem` class. I've wired everything up but I keep getting an error.

```
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
```

No matter what I do or how I tweak the code. Here is the actual code.

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HomeItemsSource = homeItemsVM.GetItems();
        BindingContext = this;
        Title = "Home";
    }

    private HomeItemsVM homeItemsVM = new HomeItemsVM();
    public ObservableCollection<HomeItem> HomeItemsSource { get; set; }

    public class HomeItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
    public DataTemplate SingleTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate MultipleTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((HomeItem)item).Type == HomeItem.ItemType.Singular ? SingleTemplate : MultipleTemplate;
    }
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="singleTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <views:CardHolder Margin="0,0,0,18"
                              BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center"
                              Items="{Binding Items}">
                              ...
            </views:CardHolder>

<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalOptions="Fill"
          ItemsSource="{Binding HomeItemsSource}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplateSelector}"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="True" />
```

HomeItem.cs

```
public class HomeItem : ObservableCollection<FeaturedItem>
{
    //public ObservableCollection<FeaturedItem> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FeaturedItem>();
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Contributor { get; set; }
...
}
```

Please what do I do?

Comment: Is ViewCell being used as a DataTemplate in a ListView?  Then each row of the ListView will contain a CardHolder?

Comment: @Jason Yes it is, I didn't think I needed to post the whole. Why?

Comment: What is your LIstView ItemsSource?

Comment: @Jason Edits made, hope it makes some sense?

Comment: Where is `itemTemplateSelector` defined?

Comment: @Jason I added the implementation